# Resume Failed Cypress Test

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a query related to the Cypress test. Is there any way in which we can resume the test from where it failed after doing amendments in the code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so there is a way where you run your tests, if test fails, then fix it and then resume from that point in Cypress (or in any tool AFAIK). In Cypress there is a `pause` functionality which pauses the execution for a certain duration of time, but I'm not sure it would be of much help for you.

Comment: So should I add a check that if I don't get a certain locator or something within some time pause the code? Then after amendments, I should resume it manually?

Answer (score 0):

At current point, there is on `Retry` option available in cypress and execution starts from very start if anything gets fail

Comment: I tried it, but it did not help. It retried for the same error thrice and then it threw an error